# J2CA0030E, J2CA0056I and J2CA0206W errors in WAS 8.5

Tags: websphere, maximo

I am getting the below errors when my application trying send the response messages.

[2/15/17 14:25:09:341 AEDT] 0000e283 ConnectionEve W   J2CA0206W: A connection error occurred.  To help determine the problem, enable the Diagnose Connection Usage option on the Connection Factory or Data Source. This is the multithreaded access detection option. Alternatively check that the Database or MessageProvider is available.

[2/15/17 14:25:09:346 AEDT] 0000e283 ConnectionEve A   J2CA0056I: The Connection Manager received a fatal connection error from the Resource Adapter for resource jms/amq/IB2B_qcf. The exception is: javax.jms.JMSException: Connection refused:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: `JMSException: Connection refused:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` - you either provided wrong host , port or you have firewall blocking traffic. Verify using ping and telnet that you can actually connect from the WAS machine to the queue manager. Also describe which qm are you using and whether it is on the same or remote host.

Comment: @Gas We are connecting to AMQ which is hosted on remote host. I have verified the firewall ping test thru port 61616. Everything is fine. We are observing this errors intermittently. Is there any other thing I need to check,